# How to Add to Cart when item is added?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have list of products where I have added functionality for add, decrement, and update of quantity value for each product.

now I want when a user adds and update the quantity of any product and click add to cart, the selected item should be added in another Array of object. so that I can show the order list separately.

[Expo Link for Code](https://snack.expo.io/@sushil62/7c7c10)

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the body of your post to form a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already storing the data in context. You just have to filter to get the added data.

```
const orderArr=product.filter((item => item.qNum !=0));
```

I hope this can help. Happy Coding.